# Syntax Error I do not understand why it is happening

Tags: python, sockets, syntax-error

So I am currently building a blogging type system from scratch in python and I am currently trying to run my blog creation program and I keep getting an error saying

```
File "create.py", line 55
cc.sendall(rp)
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my full code thanks in advance to any responses I get.
    import socket, os

```
HOST, PORT = '', 8080

ls = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ls.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
ls.bind((HOST, PORT))
ls.listen(1)

while True:
    cc, ca = ls.accept()
    rq = cc.recv(1024)
    rp = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<html>
Post succesfully posted! Return to <a href='http://192.168.0.228/'>the 
homepage</a>?
</html>
 """
    substrings = []
    substrings.insert(0, rq[rq.find("GET ")+3:rq.find(" HTTP/1.1")])
    if substrings[0] != ' /favicon.ico':
        substrings.insert(1, rq[12:rq.find("&")])
        substrings.insert(2, rq[rq.find("&")+7:len(substrings[0])+3])
        f = open("posts/{}.html".format(substrings[1]), "w+")
        f.write("""\
    <html>
    <title>
    {}
    </title>
    <script>
    function createcomment(){
            url = {}
            comment = prompt('What is your comment?');
            newurl = "http://192.168.0.228:8888/name?=" + url + "&comment?=" + comment;
            document.location.href = newurl;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <p>
    {}
    </p>
    <button onclick="createcomment()">Comment</button>
    </body>
    </html>
            """.format(substrings[1], substrings[1], substrings[2])
            cc.sendall(rp)
            cc.close()
```

So it was just that )
but now I am getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create.py", line 54, in <module>
""".format(substrings[1], substrings[1], substrings[2]))
KeyError: '\n\t\turl = {}\n\t\tcomment = prompt(\'What is your comment?\');\n\t\tnewurl = "http'
```

Comment: It looks like it's too indented, although I'd expect a different error from that.

Comment: yeah thanks, I tried messing around with the indentation before that and as you say I would expect a different error from that.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` for the write function ... `.format(substrings[1], substrings[1], substrings[2]))`, also cc.sendall is too indented.

Comment: As is commonly the case in unexplained syntax errors, it's a missing close parenthesis on the line before (closing the `f.write(...` from 20 lines earlier).  If your editor can't show you matching parentheses/brackets/etc. - throw it away, and get one that's actually suitable for programming.

Comment: thank you everyone, my editor (vim does show that stuff) I just did not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

just solve the indent problem in your last 2 line of your code

```
HOST, PORT = '', 8080

ls = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ls.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
ls.bind((HOST, PORT))
ls.listen(1)

while True:
    cc, ca = ls.accept()
    rq = cc.recv(1024)
    rp = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<html>
Post succesfully posted! Return to <a href='http://192.168.0.228/'>the 
homepage</a>?
</html>
 """
    substrings = []
    substrings.insert(0, rq[rq.find("GET ")+3:rq.find(" HTTP/1.1")])
    if substrings[0] != ' /favicon.ico':
        substrings.insert(1, rq[12:rq.find("&")])
        substrings.insert(2, rq[rq.find("&")+7:len(substrings[0])+3])
        f = open("posts/{}.html".format(substrings[1]), "w+")
        f.write("""\
    <html>
    <title>
    {}
    </title>
    <script>
    function createcomment(){
            url = {}
            comment = prompt('What is your comment?');
            newurl = "http://192.168.0.228:8888/name?=" + url + "&comment?=" + comment;
            document.location.href = newurl;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <p>
    {}
    </p>
    <button onclick="createcomment()">Comment</button>
    </body>
    </html>
            """.format(substrings[1], substrings[1], substrings[2])
    cc.sendall(rp)
    cc.close()
```